# Orchestra.MahApps custom window

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro, catel, orchestra

I'm trying to create custom MahApps.Metro window with Orchestra framework.

I have copied currennt ShellWindow content (both view + code behind) and created my own Window. Then in `App.xaml.cs` I have used my window instead of `ShellWindow` like this:

```
shellService.CreateWithSplash<MyShellWindowView>()
```

And problem is, that this window is not correctly styled (for example, minimize/max/close buttons)

[image: problem]

Here's my window:

```
<orchestra:MetroDataWindow x:Class="CatelApp.Views.MyShellWindowView"
                         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                         xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
                         xmlns:orchestra="https://github.com/orcomp/orchestra"
                         SaveWindowPosition="False" d:DesignHeight="696" d:DesignWidth="480" mc:Ignorable="d">

  <orchestra:MetroDataWindow.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style TargetType="catel:TabControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabControl}}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </orchestra:MetroDataWindow.Resources>

  <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="15, 5, 15, 5">

      <StatusBar x:Name="statusBar" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <orchestra:AnimatingTextBlock x:Name="statusTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
          <orchestra:AnimatingTextBlock.ShowStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
            </Storyboard>
          </orchestra:AnimatingTextBlock.ShowStoryboard>
          <orchestra:AnimatingTextBlock.HideStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
            </Storyboard>
          </orchestra:AnimatingTextBlock.HideStoryboard>
        </orchestra:AnimatingTextBlock>
      </StatusBar>

      <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" />
    </DockPanel>
  </Border>

</orchestra:MetroDataWindow>
```

And code behind

```
namespace CatelApp.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MyShellWindowViewModel.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyShellWindowView : MetroDataWindow, IShell
    {
        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ShellWindow"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public MyShellWindowView()
        {
            var serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.Default;

            var themeService = serviceLocator.ResolveType<IThemeService>();
            ThemeHelper.EnsureApplicationThemes(GetType().Assembly, themeService.ShouldCreateStyleForwarders());

            MahAppsHelper.ApplyTheme();

            InitializeComponent();

            var accentColorBrush = ThemeHelper.GetAccentColorBrush();
            border.BorderBrush = accentColorBrush;

            var statusService = serviceLocator.ResolveType<IStatusService>();
            statusService.Initialize(statusTextBlock);

            var commandManager = serviceLocator.ResolveType<ICommandManager>();
            var flyoutService = serviceLocator.ResolveType<IFlyoutService>();
            var mahAppsService = serviceLocator.ResolveType<IMahAppsService>();

            serviceLocator.RegisterInstance<IAboutInfoService>(mahAppsService);

            var flyouts = new FlyoutsControl();
            foreach (var flyout in flyoutService.GetFlyouts())
            {
                flyouts.Items.Add(flyout);
            }

            Flyouts = flyouts;

            var windowCommands = mahAppsService.GetRightWindowCommands();

            if (mahAppsService.GetAboutInfo() != null)
            {
//              var aboutWindowCommand = WindowCommandHelper.CreateWindowCommandButton("appbar_information", "about");

//              var aboutService = serviceLocator.ResolveType<IAboutService>();
//              commandManager.RegisterAction("Help.About", aboutService.ShowAbout);
//              aboutWindowCommand.Command = commandManager.GetCommand("Help.About");

//              windowCommands.Items.Add(aboutWindowCommand);
            }

            RightWindowCommands = windowCommands;

            var mainView = mahAppsService.GetMainView();
            contentControl.Content = mainView;

            SetBinding(TitleProperty, new Binding("ViewModel.Title") {Source = mainView});
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you include the MahApps themes in your app resources? For example, see the code below:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />

    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />

    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```